# Regex find all integers that don't start with '$'

Tags: python, regex

I want to match all integers that don't start with the dollar sign $.

For example, in

"I spent $100 on 10 12-inch subs",

I want to extract 10 and 12 but not 100.

I tried the following:

```
\b(?!\$)\d+\b
```

and I don't understand why it's not working.  If, for example, I replace the '\$' with '1', it'll give me numbers that don't start with '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for sequences of decimal digits that are not preceded by `$` (and other decimal digits).

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<![\$\d])(\d+)", "I spent $100 on 10 12-inch subs")
['10', '12']
```

Comment: There is no need to use character class in lookbehind when all OP wants is to avoid matching `$` before a digit.

Comment: Without the `\d` in the lookbehind part it finds also `'00'` and this is not correct.

Comment: That's why you need word boundary as OP was trying and what I used in my answer.

Comment: Your answer is smart and I like it. I just provide a little bit different solution.

Answer (score 9):

You need a **negative lookbehind**:

```
(?<!\$)\b\d+\b
```

This will find all integers not preceded by `$`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE3aX3/1)

Comment: I like the way you approached it using the word boundaries.  I would have approached it like this `(?<![$\d])\d+` but in some ways I like yours better.